# SharePoint User swipe

Tags: sharepoint-2007, authentication

I have a SharePoint site developed in MOSS 2007. My site is using SharePOint farm architecture which includes following servers in it

1. One Application server APP1
2. Two Database Server's  mirrored (DB1,DB2)
3. Two Front End Server's (WFE1, WFE2)**

Recently we are receiving complaints from customer saying that when A user logging with his credentails and navigate to site, sub-sites in it. When he click on Home (Root site) Tab he certainly loose his active looged in session and he see the home page for another user with his access previllages.

Can some one tell me what is the root cause for this...?

Any help will be highly appriciated.

FYI: I have implemented caching to improve the performance of this site.

Thanks & Regards,

Sachin k

Comment: Can you tell us the design of caching and type of authentication used ?

Comment: Hi Madhur, Thanks for your quick reply. I am using windows authentication and I have implemented Blob caching (http://weblogs.asp.net/hiransalvi/archive/2008/02/10/configuring-blob-caching-for-sharepoint-web-application.aspx). to speed up the performance of the site. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: How are you handling load balancing? Is it NTLM/Kerberos ? How are you identifying that user sees another user's home page ?

Comment: load balancing use kerberos. This is an issue reported by one of our customer. He is accessing the site (Production version). After navigating to sub-sites when he click on root site(Home tab) he see a diffrent login name on SharePoint Welcome control. We are having some audiance targeted web part. so He can able to view the information which he is not having access to view.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the problem with setting of Load Balancer. Special care needs to be taken when SharePoint is load balanced under kerberos.

See:

http://sharepointspot.blogspot.com/2007/09/kerberos-load-balanced-web-sites.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2007/01/05/nlb-network-load-balancing-and-sharepoint-troubleshooting-and-configuration-tips.aspx

Specifically:
To manage session transfer:
Use ASP.NET SQL Session management so all sessions are recorded in a central location OR

Use affinity on the switch so that concurrent requests from a particular IP address within the same session go to the same target server

Comment: Hi Madhur, Thanks a ton. One more thing here is, whenever such a problem arises user see home page for a specific user every time.